# How to sum the fields depends on another field's value

Tags: jquery

```
$("table").keyup(function () {
var sum = 0;
$("input").each(function() {
    if (!Number.isNaN(parseInt(this.value))) {
        sum = sum + parseInt(this.value);
    }
});

$("div").text(sum);
});
```

I have table of fields. I already know how to sum all of the text fields, but what I'm try to do is sum the text fields that have a select field value of 1.

Comment: Post your html code please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
 $("table").keyup(function () {
    var sum = 0;
    $("input").each(function () {
        if ($(this).closest("td").prev("td").find("select").val() == 1) {
            if (!Number.isNaN(parseInt(this.value))) {

                sum = sum + parseInt(this.value);
            }
        }
    });

    $("div").text(sum);
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/K57jr/13/)

How it is work

```
 $(this).closest("td") // select closest parent td
     .prev("td")          // select prev td
     .find("select").val() // find drop down and get value
```

Comment: thanks! but i modified a bit, and also works
$(this).closest("tr").find("select").val() == 1

Answer (score 0):

Try this : You can iterate `select` tag and check if selected value is equal to 1, then read text value which is present in next `td`

```
$("table").keyup(function () {
    var sum = 0;
    $("select").each(function() {
        if($(this).val()=="1")
        {
           // get parend  td -> next to parent td -> read input value
           var val = $(this).closest('td').next().find('input').val(); 

           if (!Number.isNaN(parseInt(val))) 
           {
            sum = sum + parseInt(val);
           }
        }
    });

    $("div").text(sum);
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/K57jr/12/)**

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution for both approach, when you change the `option` or on `keyup`.. [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/K57jr/14/)..

```
$("table").keyup(function () {
    var sum = 0;
    $("input").each(function() {
        if ($(this).parent().prev().find("#select_list").val() == 1 && !Number.isNaN(parseInt(val))) {
            sum = sum + parseInt(this.value);
        }
    });
    $("div").text(sum);
});
$("select").change(function(){
    var sum = 0;
    $("select").each(function() {
        if($(this).val()=="1")
        {
            var val = $(this).parent().next().find('input').val(); 
            if (!Number.isNaN(parseInt(val))) {
                sum = sum + parseInt(val);
            }
        }
    });
    $("div").text(sum);
});
```